# OpenVPN and TAP-Windows

Tags: openvpn

I was looking at my installed programs and noticed 2 programs without a publisher designation and installed on 08/21/2016. These programs are OpenVPN and TAP-Windows. Before I delete them, I wanted to know if it was installed by a TOR Browser update, and if so, are these programs necessary for using the TOR Browser?
 I cannot think of any other possible way that these programs could have been installed without my consent.

Comment: Nope, not Tor Browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Tor Browser Bundle does not install any other software as far as I am aware. OpenVPN and TAP-Windows are used for VPN connections, and are not associated with Tor.